# MS SQL срастить взаимосвязанный запрос с with запросом

Tags: sql

Есть 2 запроса, оба выполняются отлично, но по отдельности.

**Запрос 1:**

```
WITH t1_CTE (t1_Дата, index_Дата)
AS
(
    SELECT [Дата] AS t1_Дата,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Дата ASC) - 1 AS index_Дата
    FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Testing]
    WHERE Дата >= CONCAT(SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 1, 4), SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 6, 2), SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 9, 2)) AND Дата <= CONCAT(SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 1, 4), SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 6, 2), SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 9, 2))
    GROUP BY Дата
)
SELECT t1_Дата AS Select_day
FROM t1_CTE
WHERE index_Дата = 0 --20210810
```

`Дата` - хранится в числовом виде, например **20210810**. Но в запрос попадает в строковом виде **2021-08-10**

**Запрос 2:**

```
SELECT IIF([Наименование субъекта] IS NULL, 'Не задано', [Наименование субъекта]) AS Area,
       [Наименование текущего владельца] AS Kontragent,
       SUM([Количество упаковок]) AS cnt,
       [Дата] AS Select_day
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Testing]
WHERE Дата = '20210810'
AND case when [Наименование субъекта] is null then 'Не задано' else [Наименование субъекта] end in ('Пермский край', 'Московская область')
GROUP BY [Наименование субъекта], [Наименование текущего владельца]
ORDER BY SUM([Количество упаковок]) DESC
```

В этом запросе нет смысла объяснять функциональность. Нужно лишь в `WHERE Дата =`  подставить `Select_day`.
Вопрос без создание таблиц и заполнения данных. Хочу лишь понять как возможно их срастить.

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64) Nov 1 2020 00:48:37 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

**UPDATE**
Решил свои образом:

```
WITH t1_CTE (t1_Дата, index_Дата)
AS
(
    SELECT [Дата] AS t1_Дата,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Дата ASC) - 1 AS index_Дата
    FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Testing]
    WHERE Дата >= CONCAT(SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 1, 4), SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 6, 2), SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 9, 2)) AND Дата <= CONCAT(SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 1, 4), SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 6, 2), SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 9, 2))
    GROUP BY Дата
)
SELECT IIF([Наименование субъекта] IS NULL, 'Не задано', [Наименование субъекта]) AS Area,
       [Наименование текущего владельца] AS Kontragent,
       SUM([Количество упаковок]) AS cnt
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Testing]
LEFT JOIN t1_CTE ON Дата = t1_Дата 
WHERE Дата = t1_CTE.t1_Дата
AND index_Дата = 0
AND case when [Наименование субъекта] is null then 'Не задано' else [Наименование субъекта] end in ('Пермский край')
GROUP BY [Наименование субъекта], [Наименование текущего владельца]
ORDER BY SUM([Количество упаковок]) DESC
```

Comment: 1) LEFT JOIN нужно заменить на INNER 2) `WHERE Дата = t1_CTE.t1_Дата` не нужен, ибо достаточно проверить один раз, в ON 3) В CTE можно не отнимать единицу, и соответственно тогда сравнить снаружи с единицей 4) `... AND case when [Наименование субъекта] is null then 'Не задано' else [Наименование субъекта] end in ('Пермский край') ...` лучше заменить на `... AND [Наименование субъекта] = 'Пермский край' ...`

Comment: @Akina, 4) у меня массив субъектов с множественным выбором, поэтому `in`

Comment: *у меня массив субъектов с множественным выбором* Это уже не SQL, это где-то на клиенте...

Comment: @Akina, вопрос закрыт, решение есть. Всё остальное уже не важно. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Превращаешь внешний запрос из первого запроса в ещё один CTE, и используешь во втором запросе.

```sql
WITH
-- CTE первого запроса 
t1_CTE (t1_Дата, index_Дата)
AS
(
    SELECT [Дата] AS t1_Дата,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Дата ASC) - 1 AS index_Дата
    FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Testing]
    WHERE Дата >= CONCAT(SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 1, 4), SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 6, 2), SUBSTRING('2021-08-10', 9, 2)) AND Дата <= CONCAT(SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 1, 4), SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 6, 2), SUBSTRING('2021-08-26', 9, 2))
    GROUP BY Дата
),
-- внешний запрос, преобразованный в CTE
query1_cte AS (
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(t1_Дата AS nvarchar), 1, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(CAST(t1_Дата AS nvarchar), 5, 2), '-', SUBSTRING(CAST(t1_Дата AS nvarchar), 7, 2)) AS Select_day
FROM t1_CTE
WHERE index_Дата = 0
) 
-- второй запрос
SELECT IIF([Наименование субъекта] IS NULL, 'Не задано', [Наименование субъекта]) AS Area,
       [Наименование текущего владельца] AS Kontragent,
       SUM([Количество упаковок]) AS cnt,
       [Дата] AS Select_day
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Testing]
-- с использованием второго CTE вместо WHERE с вручную скопированным значением
JOIN query1_cte ON [DB1].[dbo].[Testing].Дата = query1_cte.Select_day
AND case when [Наименование субъекта] is null then 'Не задано' else [Наименование субъекта] end in ('Пермский край', 'Московская область')
GROUP BY [Наименование субъекта], [Наименование текущего владельца]
ORDER BY SUM([Количество упаковок]) DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо, но каким- то образом решил уже. Всегда так. Сколько думаю, потом задаю вопрос и приходит решение в голову. Добавил свой вариант в UPDATE

Comment: Akina, есть ли разница с моим решением?

Comment: Конечно, есть. Ваше решение компактнее. Я ж не смотрел логику, я просто показал, как можно объединить, передать результат одного запроса в другой.

Comment: Значит моя проблема в чём-то другом((. Запрос работает на ура, но визуальная программа не выводит нужную информацию. Но всё равно спасибо

Comment: @MaxDown *Запрос работает на ура, но визуальная программа не выводит нужную информацию.* Вот этой фразы не понял от слова "совсем"... полное ощущение, что при прямом выполнении получается правильный результат, а через программу - хрень голимая.

Comment: Akina, именно так, но это уже дело не этого вопроса